# How can I load a JSON file with Lunr data in JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lunrjs

I've made a JSON file with Lunr search data according to [the instructions here](https://lunrjs.com/guides/getting_started.html). So it's a JSON file that's structured like `{"documents":[{"body":"...`.

And I can manage to run these commands fine in the console:

```
var response = $.getJSON('/includes/js/lunr-index.json');
var docs = response.responseJSON.documents;
```

Yet when I have the same thing in my script, like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var response = $.getJSON('/includes/js/lunr-index.json');
    var docs = response.responseJSON.documents;

    var idx = lunr(function () {
        this.ref('title');
        this.field('body');

        docs.forEach(function (doc) {
            this.add(doc);
        }, this);
    });
});
```

I get `Cannot read property 'documents' of undefined`.

Is there something missing about JQuery's `.getJSON` method? I'm not a Javascript programmer, so sorry in advance.

Here's what it looks like when I run it in the console:

```
>>> var response = $.getJSON('/includes/js/lunr-index.json');

>>> response

{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}

>>> var docs = response.responseJSON.documents;

docs
(53) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

So the JSON works. It's just that this doesn't work in the script.

Edit:

Ok, so this looks like an async issue. I've been trying to rewrite it like this:

```
fetch('/includes/js/lunr-index.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => lunr(function () {
        this.ref('title');
        this.field('body');

        json.documents.forEach(function (doc) {
            this.add(doc);
        }, this);
    }));
```

But I don't think I know how this promise stuff works.

Comment: can you `console.log(response)` to see the structure. Maybe `response.responseJSON.documents` is not a JSON?

Comment: Can you share the content of `/includes/js/lunr-index.json` ?

Comment: If this `{documents = [ ... ]}` is not a typo in this post, then the `=` is a problem. Not allowed in JSON. Which leads me to believe that there are more syntax errors in the JSON-file.

Comment: The JSON isn't the problem, since it loads fine in the console. But when I load it in the script, it comes back as undefined.

Comment: What's the content of `response`?

Comment: I added what my console output looks like. It just doesn't work in the script.

Comment: This is a typical `async` issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Hm yeah I guess this is an async issue. Is there a way I can rewrite this with `fetch`?

Comment: `$.getJSON( "/includes/js/lunr-index.json", function( data ) {});` and you can consume the data